# How to monitor actor system termination

Tags: c#, .net, akka, akka.net

I've created my root actor:

```
        topicRootActor = actorSystem.ActorOf(actorSystem.DI().Props<RootActor>(), typeof(RootActor).Name + '.' + topic);
        topicRootActor.Tell(initMessage);
```

And when it stopped because of permanent connection failure or something else, I want to stop the application.

My idea is to stop root actor and then to call Context.System.Terminate in PostStop override. The question is how the creator of ActorSystem will know about actor system termination?

Comment: I have never worked with actors myself, but my understanding of an idea about actors is to let single actors crash, but keep the system up and running. So, there might be no easy solution. I am curious if people have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use `actorSystem.WhenTerminated`, which is a property on the ActorSystem that returns a `Task` which completes when the ActorSystem has been shutdown.

If you put a continuation on this, or await it, you should be able to shutdown your application cleanly.